# Apply instead of loop

Tags: r

I am using a for loop in order to remove every column of my data set where standard deviation = 0. I would like to do that with the apply function, do you have an idea?

```
sds<-apply(Dataset,2,sd, na.rm = FALSE)

counter=0
for(i in 1:length(sds)){
  if(sds[i]==0){
    Dataset<-Dataset[,-(i+5-counter)]
    counter=counter+1
  }
}
```

Comment: `Dataset <- Dataset[, sds!=0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(sd, Dataset)
#  col2         col3
#1     1 -0.545880758
#2     2  0.536585304
#3     3  0.419623149
#4     4 -0.583627199
#5     5  0.847460017
#6     6  0.266021979
#7     7  0.444585270
#8     8 -0.466495124
#9     9 -0.848370044
#10   10  0.002311942

sapply(Dataset, sd)
#     col1      col2      col3 
#0.0000000 3.0276504 0.5798524
```

Or use

```
Dataset[sapply(Dataset,sd)!=0]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
Dataset <- data.frame(col1 = 1, col2 = 1:10, col3 = rnorm(10))
```

Comment: Do you mean that if i write Filter(sd, Dataset) will remove the columns that has sd = 0? I tried that and i get numeric(0). I also tried Filter(sd > 0, Dataset) but no luck

Comment: @JamesMarshall  Please use the data I showed.  It is giving me columns that have sd !=0